# Client window won't closed when connected to server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, netbeans, network-programming

i have made server and client app (separate jar files)
the server can only send file(s) to the client(s), and the client(s) can only accept whatever file(s) sent by the server.

My question is, why does my client app window won't close (when the close button is pressed) until the server is closed first ?

here's my code :

server side

```
public sServerUI() {
    super("Server : "+System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")); // mendapatkan nama komputer
    initComponents();
}
public void startListener(){    
    Random randomGen = new Random();
    int myPort = randomGen.nextInt(9999);
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(myPort);//Bebas portnya, tp nggk boleh sudah terpakai atau pakai random jg bisa
        btnListen.setEnabled(false);
        while(_key == null) {
            _key = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Input your Key : ", "Insert Key", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        if(_key.equals("")) {
            _key = "Random";
            txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Invalid key inputted, key automatically set to '"+_key+"'\n");
        } else txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Key set to '"+_key+"'\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {//Kalau sudah terpakai muncul error
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not listen at " + myPort);
        //Gagal, keluarin info
    } finally{
        myPort = server.getLocalPort();
        lblPort.setText("Port: "+myPort);
        System.out.println("Port: "+myPort);
    }

    _acceptClient.start();
}
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    try {
        server.close();
        for (int i=0;i<_numberOfClient;i++){
            //socketIn[i].close();
            _socketOut[i].close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}

class Accepter extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            try{
                client[_numberOfClient] = server.accept();
                _numberOfClient++;
                lblStatus.setText("Status: "+_numberOfClient+" client(s) connected");

                Handler handleClient = new Handler(_numberOfClient-1);
                handleClient.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Accept failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
class Handler extends Thread{
    private int arr;
    Handler(int ar){
        arr = ar;
        try{
            //socketIn[arr] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client[arr].getInputStream()));
            _socketOut[arr] = new DataOutputStream(client[arr].getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Read failed");
        }
    }
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    btnListen = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtMessage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnSend = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblPort = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    fileBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setResizable(false);

    btnListen.setText("Start Listening");
    btnListen.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnListenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblStatus.setText("Status: no client connected");

    txtMessage.setEditable(false);
    txtMessage.setColumns(20);
    txtMessage.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtMessage);

    btnSend.setText("Send");
    btnSend.setEnabled(false);
    btnSend.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnSendActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblPort.setText("Port: ");

    fileBtn.setText("Choose File");
    fileBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            fileBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnListen)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(lblStatus)
                    .addGap(0, 133, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(lblPort, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 209, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnSend))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(fileBtn)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnListen)
                .addComponent(lblStatus))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(9, 9, 9)
            .addComponent(fileBtn)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnSend)
                .addComponent(lblPort))
            .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnListenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    startListener();
}
private void btnSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(_numberOfClient > 0) {
        int packetIndex = 1;
        String ext = getExt(_filePath, '.');
        byte fileChunk[];

        int k = 0;
        int blockIndex = 0;
        sendHeader("start "+_binaryData.length+" "+ext+" ");
        txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Sending file ...\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < _binaryData.length; i++) {
            if(k >= Math.ceil((double)_binaryData.length/10.0) || i == _binaryData.length-1) {
                if(i == _binaryData.length-1) k++;
                fileChunk = new byte[k];
                for(int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
                    fileChunk[x] = _binaryData[blockIndex];
                    blockIndex++;
                }
                printByteArr("file chunk : ", fileChunk);
                sendHeader(packetIndex+" ");
                packetIndex++;
                sendData(rc4(_key, fileChunk));
                k = 0;
            }
            k++;
        }
        sendHeader("end");
        txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"File Sent !\n\n");
    } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No Client Connected !", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}                                       

private void fileBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("d:/Kul/Smstr 6/Kripto n Steno/Stream Cipher/"));
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        _filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        try {
            _file = new File(_filePath);
            _fis = new FileInputStream(_file);
            _binaryData = new byte[(int)_file.length()];
            System.out.println("file size : "+(int)_file.length()+" byte(s)");
            System.out.print("Isi file : ");
            _fis.read(_binaryData);
            _fis.close();
            for(int i = 0; i < _binaryData.length; i ++) {
                System.out.print(_binaryData[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("end of file\n");

            String stringBuatDitampilin = getExt(_filePath, (char)92);

            txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText() + "'" + stringBuatDitampilin + "' Loaded !\n");
            btnSend.setEnabled(true);
        } catch(java.io.IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString(), "IO Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sServerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new sServerUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

client side

```
public sClientUI() {
    super("Client");
    initComponents();
}
public void listenSocket(){
//Create _socket connection
    try{
        _socket = new Socket(txtHost.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText()));
        _socketIn = new DataInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
        txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Succesfully connected to "+txtHost.getText()+" !\n");
        while(_key == null) {
            _key = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Input your Key : ", "Insert Key", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        if(_key.equals("")) {
            _key = "Random";
            txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Invalid key inputted, key automatically set to '"+_key+"'\n");
        } else txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Key set to '"+_key+"'\n");
        txtHost.setEditable(false);
        txtPort.setEditable(false);
        btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
        myListener = new Timer(250, readLine);
        myListener.start();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unknown host: "+e.getMessage(), "Unknown Hostname", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch  (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Either your hostname is wrong, or you entered wrong port number\n"+e.getMessage(),"Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(),"Invalid Port Number", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    try {
        _socket.close();
        _socketIn.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
ActionListener readLine = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try{
            int mLen;
            byte tempReceiver[];
            String header;

            if((header = _socketIn.readUTF()) != null) {
                if(!_readingHeader) {
                    if(!header.equals("end")) {
                        mLen = _socketIn.readInt();
                        System.out.println("mLen : "+mLen);
                        tempReceiver = new byte[mLen];
                        _socketIn.readFully(tempReceiver, 0, mLen);
                        printByteArr("bytes : ", tempReceiver);
                        txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Packet-"+header+" received : "+convertToString(tempReceiver)+"\n");
                        processBinaryData(rc4(_key, tempReceiver)); 
                    } else {
                        _binaryIndex = 0;
                        txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"All packets downloaded !\n");
                        try {
                            String namaBaru = "File Output";
                            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(namaBaru+"."+_fileExt)) {
                                out.write(_binaryData);
                            } // ga perlu di close, karena sudah pake try-with-resource. fungsi ini otomatis close file yang sudah di try
                            txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+namaBaru+"."+_fileExt+" has been created !"+"\n\n");
                        } catch(FileNotFoundException f) {
                            System.out.println("Error : " + f.getMessage());
                        } catch(IOException io) {
                            System.out.println("Error : " + io.getMessage());
                        }
                        printByteArr("Complete File : ", _binaryData);
                        System.out.println(header);
                        _readingHeader = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    processHeader(header);
                    System.out.println("header : "+header);
                    txtMessage.setText(txtMessage.getText()+"Receiving new file ...\n");
                    _readingHeader = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Read failed");
        }
    }
};
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtMessage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtHost = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtPort = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnConnect = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    txtMessage.setEditable(false);
    txtMessage.setColumns(20);
    txtMessage.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtMessage);

    jLabel2.setText("Hostname: ");

    jLabel3.setText("Port: ");

    btnConnect.setText("Connect");
    btnConnect.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnConnectActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(txtHost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(txtPort, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnConnect)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(txtHost, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(txtPort, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnConnect)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 212, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                
private void btnConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    listenSocket();
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sClientUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new sClientUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must close your client socket before closing client window...